# Changing android:minSdkVersion Has No Effect

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am developing an Android app using eclipse. When I try to run my project I get the error 
`Call requires API level 13 (current min is 8): android.view.Display#getSize` which refers to the line `display.getSize(size);`.

So in the AndroidManifest.xml I made the following change:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="13"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

However when I try running the project again, I still get the same error. The target SDK is `Android 4.0`. Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: try cleaning the project once.

Comment: Or cleaning lint markers.

Comment: Change target in default.properties to target=android-13

Comment: What is your emulator or testing device os version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clean your project. If it still shows error after cleaning then right click on project goto Properties>Android tab and select the `Android Build target Android 3.2`. And after performing this Build your project. I think it should work after this.